# Zeroes of Derivatives of a Holomorphic Function in a Bounded Region

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Let $f$ be a nonconstant smooth function on $\mathbb C$ such that the set $\Gamma$ given by $\Gamma = \{z \in \mathbb C : |f(z)| = 7\}$ is a smooth simple closed curve in $\mathbb C$.  Denote $G$ the bounded region enclosed by $\Gamma$.  Assume $f$ is holomorphic in $G$.

Assume in addition that $\Gamma$ contains no zero of $f' = \partial f/\partial z$.  Suppose $f$ has $m$ zeros counting multiplicities in $G$.  How many zeros counting multiplicities does $f'$ have in $G$?  Prove your assertion.

I assume there may be an argument with argument principle (no pun intended), and/or perhaps some clever use of Rouche's Theorem.  My guess is that the answer is $m - 1$ after trying some functions, but there could be something else hidden there.

For what it's worth, we have already shown earlier that $f$ has at least one zero, which follows from the maximum princple.

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: Looks more or less identical to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4196944/42969.

Comment: Oh, okay.  I didn't see that post.  Thank you.